# Ember Project not Working Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ember.js

I am currently working on the backend of a project and wanted to pull my friends Ember front-end client to see how it looked. But, when I clone the code of git ember wont run.

I have Node installed through NVM:

```
arie@arie-UX32VD:~/Desktop/programming/git/uInternS/student$ which node
/home/arie/.nvm/versions/v0.12.2/bin/node
```

And I have tried running npm install and npm update but neither do the trick. When I run ember serve this is the response I get:

```
arie@arie-UX32VD:~/Desktop/programming/git/uInternS/student$ ember serve
An addon must define a `name` property.
```

If I generate my own new Ember project it works just fine for me to launch it. Not sure whats wrong here and couldnt find any help!

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "student",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for student goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "ember-cli": "0.2.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "0.0.8",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.4",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.10",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "student",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.11.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.16.1",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "0.3.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.15",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1"
  }
```

Npm install and bower install:

```
arie@arie-UX32VD:~/Desktop/programming/git/uInternS/student$ npm install && bower install
npm WARN package.json ember-cli-sass@4.0.0-beta.7 No README data
arie@arie-UX32VD:~/Desktop/programming/git/uInternS/student$ ember serve
An addon must define a `name` property.
arie@arie-UX32VD:~/Desktop/programming/git/uInternS/student$
```

Comment: Show your package.json and bower.json.

Comment: Added them to my post

Comment: Silly question, but you are doing `npm install && bower install` first, right?

Comment: Added to original post